# Co-exist Xcode 6.4 and 7?

Tags: xcode

Need to get a demo off that runs great in Xcode 6.4, totally has tons of work to do to get it to work in 7.0. Doable, just under a drop dead timeline.

See that 7 wiped out 6, so I can go to a backup and grab 6, do I now actually have to partition the disk? And run it from there? With both on the same drive, seems to just create problems. Just to get through a demo, then back to 7.

thanks

Comment: "With both on the same drive, seems to just create problems" Really? I've got _five_ versions of Xcode on the same drive. No problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem to have both versions on disk even in the same folder: Just rename one of the applications. The beta versions are working fine with the beta suffix, too.